# How to prevent a device on my router from accessing the Internet?

Tags: networking, internet, home-server

I'm thinking of setting up a local server on an old machine I have lying around. So that I can easily ssh into it, I would like to add it to my current network by plugging it right into my router. Currently, all my other devices access the Internet via this router, but I would like to restrict this in my server's case.

Is this something that I can set up right in the router? Or is it operating system specific (I should mention I will be virtualizing my server so it can live beside other VMs, all of them Linux)?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're getting at. Are you trying to prevent your server from accessing the internet?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. However, other devices should still be able to access the net.

Comment: You could just not give it a default gateway in the IP configuration.  That would prevent it from accessing the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modified from this [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/30026/whitelist-allowed-ips-in-out-using-iptables) question:

```
#Flush existing rules
iptables -F
# Set up default DROP rule for eth0
iptables -P INPUT DROP
# Allow existing connections to continue
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state EXISTING,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Accept everything from the 192.168.1.x network
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
# Allow connections from this host to 192.168.2.10
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: iptables rules.

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived on most commercial home routers, as well as the OS.  Just check out your routers manual.